# How to decide on the amount of concurrent actions?

Tags: go, concurrency, coroutine, goroutine

I'm currently writing an encoder and (obviously) want to make it fast.

I have a working system for doing the encoding (so every goroutine is doing the same thing) but I am struggling with finding the right amount of goroutines to run the code in. I basically want to decide on a maximum amount of Goroutines that keeps the CPU busy.

The following thoughts crossed my mind:

- If a file is only <1 kB it's not useful to run the code in a lot of goroutines
- The amount of goroutines should be influenced by the cores/threads available

  - running 16 goroutines on a 4x4 GHz CPU will not be a problem but what with a 4x1 GHz CPU?
  - hard to determine reliably cross-platform
- The CPU should be busy but not as busy as to keep other programs from responding (~70-ish %?)

  - hard to decide beforehand due to clockspeed and other parameters

Now I've tried to decide based on these factors on how many goroutines to use but I'm not quite sure how to do so cross-platform and in a reliable way.

Attempts already made:

- using a linear function to determine based on filesize

  - requires different functions based on CPU
- parsing CPU-specs from lscpu

  - not cross-platform
  - requires another function to determine based on frequency

Which have not been satisfactory.

Comment: You're thinking as though goroutines are threads. They are not. If you can partition your task into multiple smaller chunks, then it is fine to create one goroutine for each, provided goroutines are not tight-loops. If your goroutines do not perform any I/O or do not communicate with each other, you won't gain anything from such partitioning.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In fact (at least currently on the nature of goroutines, will read up on that) every goroutine is reading the file that is to be encoded so there certainly is a limit there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention in a comment that

> every goroutine is reading the file that is to be encoded

But of course the file—*any* file—is already encoded in some way: as plain text, perhaps, or UTF-8 (stream of bytes), perhaps assembled into units of "lines".  Or it might be an image stream, such an an mpeg file, consisting of some number of frames.  Or it might be a database, consisting of records.  Whatever its *input* form is, it contains some sort of basic unit that you could feed to your (re-)encoder.

That unit, whatever it may be, is a sensible place to divide work.  (*How* sensible, depends on what it is.  See the idea of *chunking* below.)

Let's say the file consists of independent lines: then use `scanner.Scan` to  read them, and pass each *line* to a channel that takes lines. Spin off N, for some N, readers that read the channel, one line at a time:

```
ch := make(chan string)
for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    go readAndEncode(ch)
}

// later, or immediately:
for s := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin); s.Scan(); {
    ch <- s.Text()
}
close(ch)
```

If there are 100 lines, and 4 readers, the first four `ch <- s.Text()` operations go fast, and the fifth one pauses until one of the readers is done encoding and goes back to reading the channel.

If individual lines are too small a unit, perhaps you should read a "chunk" (e.g., 1 MB) at a time.  If the chunk has a partial line at the end, back up, or read more, until you have a whole line.  Then send the entire data chunk.

Because channels *copy* the data, you may wish to send a reference to the chunk instead.<sup>1</sup>  This would be true of any larger data unit.  (Lines tend to be short, and the overhead of copying them is generally not very large compared to the overhead of using channels in the first place.  If your lines have type `string`, well, see the footnote.)

If line, or chunk-of-lines, are not the correct unit of work here, figure out what *is*.  Think of goroutines as people (or busy little gophers) who each get *one job* to do.  They can depend on someone else—another person or gopher—to do a smaller job, whatever that might be; and having ten people, or gophers, working on sub-tasks allows a supervisor to manage them.  If you need to do the same job N times, and N is not unbounded, you can spin off N goroutines.  If N *is* potentially unbounded, spin off a fixed number (maybe based on #cpus) and feed them work through a channel.

---

<sup>1</sup>As Burak Serdar notes, some copies can be elided automatically: e.g., strings are in effect read-only slices.  Slice types have three parts: a pointer (reference) to the underlying data, a length, and a capacity.  Copying a slice copies these three parts, but not the underlying data.  The same goes for strings: string headers omit the capacity, so sending a string through a channel copies only the two header words.  Hence many of the obvious and easy-to-code ways of chunking data will already be pretty efficient.

Comment: "Because channels copy the data..." channels of strings, byte slices will not copy the strings or slices. only the reference.

Comment: Ah, good point: strings, being readonly, don't need to be copied. Slices are headers + references so only the headers get copied, of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Due to the encoding process taking 1 byte at a time and returning one byte (and a boolean whether this byte is to be escaped) using lines seems counter-intuitive. The Encoding is for use in data-transmission of different kinds (images, videos, text, other binary things) so I can hardly use lines as it would probably limit the efficiency.

Comment: "Lines" was merely an example. As I said, it might be image frames. Apparently your unit of encoding division is "byte", so the natural division would be "byte", which is probably too small. Therefore you might upgrade to "chunk of bytes" of some suitable size, probably conveyed as `[]byte` in Go code.

Comment: Current status: I start up to 128 goroutines at a time each encoding a slice of 4 MiB (if the file is less than 512 MiB there are less goroutines). After reading up on the nature of goroutines I decided that "burn that CPU" is my way to go until enlightenment comes. Thank you for your elaborate answer, I'll mark it as a accepted since it was so informative and had great influence on this decision.